# Azure::ServiceBus subscription does not receive messages sent to topic via REST POST

Tags: ruby, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Sending messages to Azure Service Bus topic using the `Azure::ServiceBus` ruby SDK works fine. The client is using a subscription and `Azure::ServiceBus` to receive the messages.

However, if the sender uses the ASB `REST` API to `POST` a message, the subscription has no messages. Only messages sent using `Azure::ServiceBus` appear in the subscription.

e.g this works fine for messages sent using `Azure::ServiceBus` but doesn't receive anything for messages sent using `REST`:

```
message = azure_service_bus_service.receive_subscription_message("testtopic", "retry-count-subscriber", { :peek_lock => true })
```

ASB returns `201` for `POST`ing so the messages are successfully sent to the topic.

Comment: Are you sure the message is sent successfully using REST? Did you check the message count from the portal?

Comment: yes the Azure portal shows the incoming message but no outgoing one to the subscriber. If I use the SDK it shows the incoming and outgoing message that goes straight to the subscriber. Also subscribed via HTTP GET as well and the subscriber never gets the POSTed message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a `SqlFilter` on the subscriber:

```
retry_count > 9
```

The ruby post worked as it was setting it correctly:

```
message = Azure::ServiceBus::BrokeredMessage.new(message, { :retry_count => 10 })
```

changing `:retry_count` to anything less than 9 reproduced the problem in the ruby code too.

Answer (score 0):

This can work fine on my side.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
require 'json'

uri = URI('https://yourservicebusnamespacename.servicebus.windows.net/yourservicebustopicname/messages')
bearertoken = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyIsImtpZCI6Im5PbzNaRHJPRFhFSzFqS1doWHNsSFJfS1hFZyJ9.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.GE_j9d1l6XlPrmx7q8bN-gJYKaP8DFf2JUErwPsa-Ca--UbkUJ-XGlmVbAq2oRY_Z-2zsVbLQVNA0soB1NZVwDcSk3I_cJdIVK8J0jx5Yh0AE3XdFnObDd8zo4lcupwQbEZQCGx_5L_iJU1cKZwHDMVmtKPvk2X8MhM2Ks6OOftT_2Wxz-lo79pc9K7L-XPbHpyjRdAfbYxLhifDKGX4XBpViAxZ7gFGULI1FILW7VvWZU02aUTkNOVf_csO3UJLNjmgcm-_nljq1tka6nQC4YiJKo3dMtlwOUoeJwxdFn1Mblvs6xdGsvIxGvxDwRSvy8n4ySUyrapOtgoGDMi82Q"
header = {'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
          'Authorization': bearertoken  
         }
mes = "This is testbowman message."
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,   
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri,header)
  request.body = mes

  response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object 
  puts response.body
end 

puts 'Request is OK.'
```

And please don't forget to add the related add app to the RBAC role of azure service bus namespace:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification that the code is the same. The answer turned out to be a simple configuration problem

Comment: @codebrane What configuration do you mean?:) Can you share?

Comment: I've answered my own question with the problem resolution. Thanks for the pointer on the code though as it was helpful

Comment: @codebrane Please don't forget to mark the answer to end this question, it will help others who meet the similar problem.:)